# How do I stop the cat command when it's reading from an named pipe?

Tags: bash

I have named pipe that gets data very slowly but endlessly, I want to copy the contents of the named pipe to date formatted files while they arrive.

I have something like this

```
do
    cat /tmp/big_file > `printf '%(%Y/%m/%d)T' -1`.output &
    sleep 3590
    kill $!
    sleep 10
done
```

Is it safe to just kill `cat`? Or could I lose some data in its buffer? How do I tell cat it's time to stop?

Comment: It might be better to use a `while read` loop instead of `cat`.

Comment: I'm actually sending to aws s3, a web endpoint, so I'd like to keep the stdin or the aws cli open so I can keep writing to it. If it were a file I could just read line by line appending

Comment: You don't need to close stdin in order to use the `while read` approach.

Comment: Close the other end of the pipe; that will cause `cat` to exit once it finishes reading the data.

Comment: You may want to look into something like `logrotate` instead of implementing this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use `while read` you can send signals also with `kill` like in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2107/how-to-suspend-and-resume-processes By default *kill* sends `SIGTERM`. You can also send signals using C or shell code like in https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/02/send-signal-to-process/ With `SIGTSTP` you suspend a process, `SIGCONT` continues it, a list of all signals is in http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

**https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2107/how-to-suspend-and-resume-processes**

There are some pitfalls described in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149741/why-is-sigint-not-propagated-to-child-process-when-sent-to-its-parent-process

Comment: Now that I think of it, interrupting could interrupt the `cat` half way through writing a record. If I have to do read line loops into a fifo, with a timestamp check to rotate files, I think I will just use python. This helped with the decision though!